# Best Way to store information in checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working in WPF MVVM.

I need to create an array of checkboxes (that are presented to the user) - each one of them stores information about whether or not to upload a file to a server.

For example - If checkbox one is checked than file1 is uploaded.
If checkbox2 is checked the file2 is also uploaded.

What is the best way to do it? Can I create my own property that will store the file name?

I thought to implement it by using the text on the checkbox and passing it as a parameter to a command, but defining your own property and using it should be much better.

(What if I don't want to display the exact file name to the user?)

Here is what I wrote:

```
<CheckBox Name="File1" Content="File1" Command="{Binding AddFileToUpload}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=File1, Path=Content}"/>
<CheckBox Name="File2" Content="File1" Command="{Binding AddFileToUpload}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=File2, Path=Content}"/>
```

Best Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your ViewModel is set up but this is how I would approach it:

1. Create the `ObservableCollection` of objects in your ViewModel, these objects would represent your files, each with their own `IsSelected` property.
2. Create an `ItemsControl` and bind the `ObservableCollection` to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property.
3. Set the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` as an `ItemsPanelTemplate` containing a `StackPanel` or some other expandable container.
4. Set your `ItemsSource.ItemTemplate` property to a `DataTemplate` containing your checkbox, bind the `IsChecked` property to the `IsSelected` property of your object.
5. Then, create a `Button` and use a command which iterates over your `ObservableCollection`, gathering the files which have `IsSelected = true`, and continue with your process.

This way you are not storing anything directly in your View. The generation of, and data shown inside, the check boxes relies solely on the data you store in your objects and supply via the binding.

**Edit:**

Here are some links that details how to use the `ItemsControl`: [**Boop**](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) 
[**Beep**](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007041201.aspx)